# Why is Equation 2 considered to be a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

Equation two is a plane in the diagram, but it only consists of two variables.  Wouldn't that just make it a line?  The third plane (third equation) has been omitted from the diagram

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpCle.png)

Comment: The number of variables doesn't determine the dimension. For instance, $z=0$ is a plane: the $x, y$-plane. To give a line in $3$-space requires $2$ equations (for instance, $x = y = 0$ is the $z$-axis); the rule of thumb is that each equation reduces the dimension by $1$.

Comment: @RichardD.James The number of variables *that appear in the equation* doesn't determine the dimension